# spaCy SolorPower matching error: "extra fields not permitted"

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, matcher

```
    nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
    from spacy.matcher import Matcher
    matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
    patterns = [ 
    [{'Lower':'solarpower'}],
     [{'LOWER':'solar'},{'IS_PUNCT':True},{'Lower':'power'}],
     [{'Lower':'solar'},{'LOWER':'power'}]
    ]
    matcher.add('SolarPower',patterns)
```

Getting Error :

MatchPatternError: Invalid token patterns for matcher rule 'SolarPower'
Pattern 0:

- [pattern -> 0 -> Lower] extra fields not permitted
  Pattern 1:
- [pattern -> 2 -> Lower] extra fields not permitted
  Pattern 2:
- [pattern -> 0 -> Lower] extra fields not permitted

how solve this error ?